# How to find the background-position / background-image etc for multiple backgrounds using jQuery in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari

Maybe I'm missing something here.

I'm trying to get the current background info for an element (`div`) with multiple backgrounds, set using the longhand `background-repeat`, `background-position` and `background-image`.

Using jQuery, I simply do `var bPos = $('#element').css('background-position')` to get the set of current positions, which will give me something like `'0 0, 100px 100px, left bottom'` in Firefox and Chromium (currently versions 5 and 12 respectively), but in Safari (version 5 on OS-X) it just returns the first value pair (`'0 0'`). These CSS values are set in an external stylesheet.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is, and how to go about it to get the full set of value pairs in Safari (using the shorthand `background` property doesn't do it either)?

**Edit:**

Here is the CSS that is used in an external style sheet:

```
#page{
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-x;
    background-image: url('../images/line.png'), url('../images/line.png'), url('../images/line.png'), url('../images/line.png'), url('../images/line.png');
    background-position: 0 798px, 0 653px, 0 125px, 0 88px, 0 78px;
}
```

**Edit:**

Ok, I made a test case for this on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eWQNq/) and have reported it as a jQuery [bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9860) since it seems to be reproducible behaviour (although I accept that it might be a browser implementation problem rather than actually a jQuery bug).

Still, if anyone has any ideas...

**Edit:**

The jQuery ticket has been closed - I take this to mean that it is a Safari bug - I'm not quite sure how to go further from here, but I've posted a bug report with Apple.

**Edit:**

As pointed out by Sindre Sorhus, this appears to have been corrected in Safari 5.1.

Comment: Apologies if this sounds obtuse, but how exactly did you specify multiple background images for the div? (i.e. could you add your code to the question?)

Comment: Yep. It would seem the jQuery team decided that it was a bug in Safari. Apparently, there's no way to get at the full property set with or without jQuery in Safari. Unfortunately, you're dealing with very new tech here and browser implementations are not complete for really any part of CSS3 or HTML5 at this point. You'll just have to take a different path.

Comment: Fair enough, this is what it seems to be. However, I wouldn't say that this is a very new technology - yes the CSS3 specification is not set, but seeing that the other browsers manage to cope with returning the full set (let's not mention the dirty IE word), and that as far as I know Safari was the first to implement multiple backgrounds a long time ago [in 2005](http://www.webkit.org/blog/15/multiple-backgrounds/), I would have thought that they could have got round to it by now...

Comment: The testcase reports correctly in the new Safari 5.1

Comment: Thanks - yes I can confirm that. Although Apple still haven't said anything in the bug report I filed. It would be interesting to know whether the last update to 5.0xx for Leopard corrects that too...

Comment: Thumbs up for taking action and reporting the bug to apple and safari

Answer (score 1):

Since it's fixed in 5.1, I guess it's not a big deal anymore, but I wander if as a workaround you could initially set the background from js by

```
$('#page').attr('style', '...');
```

and then read it from there... 
kinda stupid and pain in the ass, yeah.

Comment: That's what I'm doing for the moment, but it upsets me having to set the style in Javascript rather than the appropriate CSS file. And I still count it as a problem even though it works in 5.1 because I cannot be sure that my users will have upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery Background Position plugin.
http://www.webinventif.fr/jquery-background-position-mettez-du-mouvement-dans-votre-background/

Comment: The links on the page you linked to don't work, and the post doesn't mention multiple backgrounds. Furthermore, if it isn't possible to get the details of multiple backgrounds in Safari, then no plugin jQuery or otherwise will be able to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use different classes. That would be easiler.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. There is already a CSS class (#page), but I need to be able to read back the values in Javascript (in the occurrence so that I can reset the background to what it was originally before I animated it). If Safari won't let me read back for one class, then it won't for another!